# Can you create a custom page with content in the center already defined?

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages, page-template

Is this possible? So for example, you select from the templates a page called "custom-blog-home" and on this page in the centre you have two section, one is a set of blogs being pulled in and styled very specifically and the other is a list of tweets coming in. These two sections are side by side and in the center of the page.

The above that you have a slider - defined by the theme - and some user input content, and below that you have a gallery the user has input into the page.

Essentially the `the_content` section would be split in two.

I am just not sure how to handle this, regardless of what the user does there must be these two sections in the centre of the page at all times and the user cannot edit them, they can place content above and below.

Would I create meta boxes one for above and one for below, and then create the page programatically?

Comment: using http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ will be the easiest way to accomplish this. hide your the_content on this page template and have two ACF fields for the content sections required.

Comment: What about using page templates http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates ?

Comment: @MarioJohnathan Thats what I just stated, this is a page template with custom content ALWAYS in the center. the user places there data above and below said content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that kind of thing your self, you could add a custom meta box that shows up only on that page template labeled something like "Second Content Area" that the user can enter additional content into for display below the center areas.

Another possibility would be to place a (horizontal) sidebar below the middle content and let the user place content there via widgets.